# Liferay Velocity Templates & Structures. Get Children of Children?

Tags: templates, liferay, velocity

I'm working with Structures and Templates within Liferay 6.1.
When trying to get children of rows it appears that the only way to access the information using a loop is with code similar to this:

```
#foreach
($this in $example.getSiblings())
<h2>$this.getData()</h2>
<p>$this.getChildren().get(0).getData()</p>
#end
```

Does anyone know how it would be possible to access the data for children of children? I've tried scouring through the Velocity user-guide for an example but cannot get anything to work.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or link some code that they think may work, it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Jay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem. Solution appears to be

```
$this.getChildren().get(3).getChildren().get(1).getData()
```

replacing the numbers in brackets in correlation with the position of the child.

Answer (score 3):

```
#foreach ( $item in $allItems )
  #set( $childrenFirstLevel = $item.getChildren())
   #foreach ( $childFirstLevel in $childrenFirstLevel)
      #set( $childrenSecondlevel = $childFirstLevel.getChildren())
      #foreach ($childSecondLevel in $childrenSecondLevel)
         <p>$childSecondLevel.data</p>
      #end 
   #end    
#end
```

You just need nested iterations to get children of children, as it holds in every programming language.

Answer (score 1):

@jkonst is giving the correct answer. Here's some additional information for you to explore velocity more. Consider to just use `$this.getChildren().getClass().getName()` - this will print the class of the backing Java object, giving you more hints on what to do with it. Same with `$this.getChildren().get(0).getClass().getName()`.

Naturally you'll use this only to explore and debug your velocity templates, but it helps a lot to get a clue what to do with the individual objects.

Comment: Check $title.fieldName.type.getData() etc. In this case the "children" are not collections but individual fields? Of course than you don't need to iterate through them, but I had the impression (just as @jkonst) that you were actually speaking about nested collections. Otherwise start with $title.getClass().getName() and look up that interface.